# How to use Collect to group negative terms?

Tags: polynomials, algebraic-manipulation

For example, I have: $-d^2-k^{d+1}+d k^d+d+k-1$.
I want to get: $-\left(d^2+k^{d+1}+1\right)+d k^d+d+k$.

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as *Mathematica* code instead of just images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you.  You may find [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: One problem is that you cannot conveniently prevent from the minus sign in `-(a + b)` from being automatically distributed.  The internal form seems unimportant (from what is said in questions), so perhaps you're only interested in formatting the output?

Comment: Thank you for the solution and for the comments. I don't even care about the format. In fact, I have long equations (type LHS == 0) and my goal is to achieve LHS == RHS with only positive terms. I thought that grouping negative members would make it easier for me to move them to the right.

Comment: You're welcome.  This is called an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  Try `Simplify[Expand@poly == 0]` on my `poly`.  See if it works for your case.

Comment: I'm afraid it doesn't work. 
`mypoly = 1 - d - 2 k - 2 d k + 2 k ^ d + 2 d k ^ d - 4 k ^ (1 + d) +  4 d k ^ (1 + d)` 
`Simplify [Expand @ mypoly == 0]` gives 
`(* d (1 + 2 k) (-1 + 2 k ^ d) == (- 1 + 2 k) (1 + 2 k ^ d) *)` 
I used your help and found: 
`tmp = -Plus @@ Select[List @@ mypoly, Internal\`SyntacticNegativeQ];`
`balancedpoly = tmp == mypoly + tmp`  Thank you again.

Comment: You're welcome. Here's another possibility: With the messed up equation `myeqn = 1 - d - 2 k - 2 d k + 2 k^d + 2 d k^d - 4 k^(1 + d) + 4 d k^(1 + d) == 0 // Simplify;`, apply the following:
`With[{eq = Expand /@ myeqn},
 SubtractSides[eq, Total@Cases[eq, _?Internal`SyntacticNegativeQ, {2}]]
 ]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test example:

```
SeedRandom[0];
poly = FromDigits[RandomInteger[{-5, 5}, 10], x]
```

> ```
> (*  1 - 5 x + 3 x^2 + x^8 (2 + 5 x) + x^4 (-4 - 3 x + (3 - 5 x) x^2)  *)
> ```

The problem is that if you separate the added and subtracted terms, when it is evaluated, the minus sign is automatically distributed and the terms sorted (since `Plus` has the `Attribute` `Orderless`).

```
1 + 3 x^2 + 3 x^6 + 2 x^8 + 5 x^9 - (5 x^7 + 3 x^5 + 4 x^4 + 5 x)
```

> ```
> (*  1 - 5 x + 3 x^2 - 4 x^4 - 3 x^5 + 3 x^6 - 5 x^7 + 2 x^8 + 5 x^9  *)
> ```

For output formatting: You can prevent `Plus` from being evaluated and sorting the monomials.  This is inconvenient for further computation — I would just let the polynomial be reordered.  However, for making a human-readable presentation, it can be done with `Defer` or `HoldForm`.  Here is one way:

```
Plus @@ KeyValueMap[
  # /. {False -> #2, True -> -Defer@Evaluate[-#2]} &,
  Total /@ GroupBy[MonomialList[poly], Internal`SyntacticNegativeQ]
  ]
```

> ```
> (*  1 + 3 x^2 + 3 x^6 + 2 x^8 + 5 x^9 - (5 x + 4 x^4 + 3 x^5 + 5 x^7)  *)
> ```

Comment: If your expression is not a polynomial, then instead of `MonomialList`, you could use `List@@Expand[expr]`.